# One to one mapping issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, mapping, one-to-one

I'm  trying to map 2 tables by one to one relation , but when I enter value for both tables on api call the child table is not getting the value.

My first entity class lang

```
---
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String description;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

---
```

My second entity class  label

```
---
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String sName;
    private String bName;
    private String label;   
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Language.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="lang.Id" ,referencedColumnName ="id")
    private Lang lang;
    public Lang getLang() {
        return lang;
    }
---
```

My service for saving the values into db

```
---

public Labels addlabel(Labels label) {
    Labels newlabel = new Labels();
Lang lang = new Lang();         newlabel.setSName(label.getSName().setLabelText(label.getLabelText()).setBName(label.getBName());                             
    return labelRepo.save(newlabel);
---
```

The body I have passed on postman on api call contain label, sname, bname, description (field of language). But the response  sets value only for label table but value of language table is null.

Can some one tell me where i got it wrong?

Comment: Please accept the proposed edits to your question so we can at least read it.